# How to see the remaining time on a locked object in couchbase document?

Tags: couchbase

If I was able to acquire a lock on a couchbase document using the `getAndLock` method in the java couchbase sdk, how would I check what's the time remaining for the lock to expire, also how would I extend the time of expiration for the lock if I already hold the lock??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just gone and checked the code of how locking is actually implemented in the server - there is literally no way of getting the expiry time and there is no way of changing the lock time without first unlocking.

Comment: Thanks @Chippiewill